# How to catch a wrong input that faker sent, so my automation doesn't crash?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, pycharm, faker

### Situation

I have a main page that shows a table of persons, and an "add new person" button. When you click on it, **a modal window appears** with multiple inputs and selects **for you to add a new person**.
The field "name" will validate for special characters.
The modal has a "save" button that will save and close the modal if every field validated OK. If you sent an invalid character, it will validate and trigger a warning message below the field in question, the modal remaining open until you fix it.

### Problem

My automation works with `faker`, and sometimes it will send names with an hyphen, causing for it to fail the given scenario (when it clicks "save", the modal won't close).

### Attempted solution

My initial thought was asking if the warning message exists or appears, try sending another.
This logic fails because when `faker` sends a valid name, the modal will close and I'd be asking for an element (the error message) that isn't visible anymore (since I'm on main once the modal closes). This throws an `ElementNotInteractableException`.

```py
def create_new_person(self):
    self.find_element(*self.__locators.NAME_INP).send_keys(helpers.generate_name_female())
    # And many other inputs...
    self.find_element(*self.__locators.SAVE_PERSON_BTN).click()
    alert = self.is_element_present(self.__locators.NAME_ALERT_MSG)
        while alert:
        self.find_element(*self.__locators.NAME_INP).send_keys(helpers.generate_name_female())
        self.find_element(*self.__locators.SAVE_PERSON_BTN).click()
```

---

Maybe I could consider a sign of success the fact that the modal closed and ask for that instead, but I'm not sure how to implement that, or if it's even possible.

**What question should I be asking to check if there was a problem while faker filled the inputs?**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Your posted code fails for undefined symbols; if fixed, the code shows no errors because the function isn't called.

Comment: I haven't used faker but have you looked to see if there's a way to add hyphen as an excluded character? If not, you can at least generate the name inside of a loop that only passes if the name is valid. Once you've validated the name, then enter it into the page. With either of these methods you can avoid the error altogether.

Comment: Thanks @JeffC - I didn't find a way to exclude special characters for `faker.name_female()` but I tried your second suggestion and modified my `generate_name_female()` method and it worked perfectly. It just never occured to me. I'm glad to have learned something today.

Answer (score 0):

```
while self.is_element_present(self.__locators.NAME_ALERT_MSG) is True:
```

First, why are you checking to see whether the return value has the same object ID as a Boolean constant?  From your description, simply

```
while self.is_element_present(self.__locators.NAME_ALERT_MSG):
```

would do.  Second, you haven't checked what value is returned on each call.  Instrument this with a local variable:

```
alert = self.is_element_present(self.__locators.NAME_ALERT_MSG)
print("alert =", alert)
while alert:
    ...
    alert = self.is_element_present(self.__locators.NAME_ALERT_MSG)
    print("alert =", alert)
```

Comment: You're very right. I edited my question and incorporated your suggestions, but I think it's more of a problem in the logic of it all. Thank you.